# How to prove the intermediate value theorem when $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Here's the theorem:

"The intermediate value theorem states the following: Consider an interval $I = [a, b]$ in the real numbers $ℝ$ and a continuous function 
$f : I → ℝ$. Then,
If $u$ is a number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$,
  $f(a) < u < f(b)$   (or  $f(a) > u > f(b)$ ),

then there is a $c ∈ (a, b)$ such that $f(c) = u$. "

What happens if we consider $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $I$ ?

Is there a simple method to prove the theorem in this case ? I know the method for $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ with $I=[a,b]$, but here it is different.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you quote the precise statement you want to prove? Can't you just start by restricting $f$ to $[a,b]$?

Comment: Your confusion is probably about how to word the statement: you might have thought that you can't just use $a$ and $b$ if $I=[a,b]$ is not given. However, Jorge's answer seem to answer your question with the correct statement.

Comment: @Berci I was searchin for a sort of generalization. For instance if we allow $a=-\infty$ and $b=+\infty$ how does the theorem work..

Comment: I think the moral of the story is that since $f$ is continuous, it takes every value between each pair of values in its image. In other words, its image is connected.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly does the intermediate value theorem say for functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$?

If it says that if $a<b$ and $t$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ then there is $x$ in $[a,b]$ so $f(x)=t$ then it can be proven using what you wrote.

Comment: if $\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ we define $g(x)=f(x)-t$ and use Bolzano's theorem. But $\mathbb{R}$ is not a compact set and $g$ is not probably defined...

Comment: Do you want to show that if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, then $f$ is surjective (i.e. for each $y\in\mathbb R$ there exists $x\in\mathbb R$ st $f(x)=y$)?

Comment: if you have those limits you can find $b$ so that $f(b)>t$ and $a$ so that $f(a)<t$

Comment: @JorgeFernández $t$ can be also $\infty$ and in this case $g$ cannot be defined.

Comment: If $t$ is infinite I can guarrantee you there is no $x$ in all of $\mathbb R$ so that $f(x)=\infty$ why? because $\infty\not\in \mathbb R$

Comment: @JorgeFernández you're right if we consider $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

In some sense we can use 
$$
c = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) \\
d = \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)
$$

Assuming $c, d$ are finite, w.l.o.g. put $c < d$ and pick some $u \in (c, d)$ then put 
$\epsilon = u - c$ and $\epsilon' = d - u$. We know there is some $M > 0$ such that 
$$
\lvert f(x) - c \rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \text{ when } x \le - M
$$
and some $N > 0$ such that
$$
\lvert f(x) - d \rvert < \frac{\epsilon '}{2} \text{ when } x \ge N
$$
Now we have the compact interval $[-M, N]$ and we may use the usual theorem.

Note that I left out a few details that you should consider:

- Is $u$ in $(f(-M), f(N))$?
- What about if the limits are infinite?

Appended:

Let's look at the case when $c = - \infty, d = + \infty$ (this is to be understood in the sense of limits of course). Pick $u \in \mathbb{R}$. We have some $M$ such that whenever $x \le -M$ we have $f(x) < u$ and some $N$ so that whenever $x \ge N$ we have $f(x) > u$. Now consider $[-M, N]$ with the usual theorem.

Comment: You understand my question, and the case where the limits are infinite seems to be more difficult... And in this case I don't know if it's better to take $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ or $f: \bar{\mathbb{R}} \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ ?

Comment: @Maman it's fine to simply take $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. As for when the limits are infinite do the same kind of deal as I did - you want to try and make a compact interval in which $u$ lies. First find some bounds for the $x$ being so that $f(x)$ is big enough (or small enough) and then you should be on your way!

Comment: So if $f: \bar{\mathbb{R}} \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ it is easier because the interval is compact ?

Comment: @Maman yes indeed

Comment: Thanks for the hint but just one point : I saw in certain books that in $\mathbb{R}$ we cannot use $\infty$ beacuse it means that if the limit is infinite it does not exist taht's why we can use $\infty$ just in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$..

Comment: @Maman added to my post - unsure what you're trying to prove if not that.

Comment: $u$ is necessary in $(f(-M),f(N))$ ?

Comment: @Maman yes it is necessary - this is how you use the IVT. You should try to work out why it's in the interval yourself!

Answer (score 1):

To the effect of your comment asking whether allowing $a=-\infty$ and or $b=\infty$ would still work (since if they were both finite, it would reduce to the previous case). The answer is *yes*, because the [extended real number line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), wherein we add $-\infty$ and $\infty$ to the number line, is isomorphic to a closed interval. In particular,
$g(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)$ is a homeomorphism from the extended real number line to $[-\frac{1}2\pi,\frac{1}2\pi]$ where we define $g(\infty)=\frac{\pi}2$ and $g(-\infty)=-\frac{1}2\pi$. (The map is also order-preserving, which can imply the theorem too)

This implies immediately that the intermediate value theorem applies to the extended real line, since the spaces are homeomorphic. Now, if $f$ can sensibly be extended to the extended real number line - that is, if $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x)$, then we may apply the theorem.

Comment: I understand ! For once a theorem is easier in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$

Comment: Do you think that Brouwer fixed-point theorem works in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ ?

Comment: @Maman Easily; the Brouwer fixed point thereom is a purely topological statement, so the fact that $[0,1]$ and $\overline{ \mathbb R}$ are homeomorphic is sufficient to show that, given that it holds in $[0,1]$, it holds in $\overline{ \mathbb R}$ - you could also note that, unless $-\infty$ or $\infty$ is a fixed point of $f$, any continuous $f$ would be have finite limits as $x$ goes towards $\infty$ or $-\infty$ and thus would be bounded, and you could apply the Brouwer fixed point theorem directly to whatever bounds $f$ falls within.

Comment: Ok because when I proved this theorem I used $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and for $f(x)=+\infty$ when $x=+\infty$, $g$ cannot be defined ! So even if it works there is something unclear with the standard proof. For instance $f : x \mapsto x^3$